# Is there a way to check if a MySQL dictionary's element contains a specific integer?

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I have a logging system in my discord bot, and I want to make a system which allows you to ignore channels, but I'm stuck with it.
Currently I have this code:

```py
cursor=db.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `logexclude` WHERE server={int(before.guild.id)}")
excluded = cursor.fetchall()
for i in excluded:
    if before.channel.id in i[1]: return
```

`excluded` is a list and it looks like this:
`[{'server': 890248334542008321, 'channel_ids': 890248758875533322, 'user_ids': 0, 'role_ids': 0}]`

However, when I try to access it's first element (`excluded[0]`), it just gives me an error:

```
    if before.channel.id in i[1]: return
TypeError: 1
```

Comment: If your elements in `excluded` are a `dictionary` each then how could you expect to parse them like a `list` (`i[1]`). You should parse them using there keys like `i[channel_ids]`. By default they should be `list` but `dictionary` flag is set `True` when `db.cursor()` function is called i.e., `cursor=db.cursor(dictionary=True)`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dictionary's element"?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries store their data in key:value pairs, so you can only access them by key (or value). You can't access them by index, there is the problem.

```py
cursor=db.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `logexclude` WHERE server=?", (before.guild.id))
excluded = cursor.fetchall()
for i in excluded:
    if i['channel_ids'] == before.channel.id: 
         return
```

This should work.

P. S. It's better to separate query and parameters using question mark (`?`), [here's described why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51313074/15277511).

P. S. S. If you want to store multiple channels in `channel_id`, you should use one-to-many relationship for your database.

Comment: Do you think this would work? the `if` block will fail because `i['channel_ids']` is `int`, not an `iterable object`.  You need to check it with a `==`.

Comment: Actually, we can ditch this `if` check if we adjust the query a little bit, like `cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM \`logexclude\` WHERE channel_ids=?", (before.channel.id))` i.e., by using `channel id` instead of fetching the data based on `guild id`.

Comment: @kite Thank you for noticing my mistake in the code, I have edited my answer.