# Python flask how can i insert a variable in LIKE sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Im struggeling on this problem with excuting sql in my flask python app.

Im trying to excecute a like function with a variable that im recieving from my get reqs.

for example i've tried this yet :

```
rows = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM vragen WHERE vraag LIKE ':text'",
                      {"text": '%' + query + '%'}).fetchall()
```

but this gives me an empty array unfortunately.

This gives me data but then im not using a variable which i need in this case.

```
rows = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM vragen WHERE vraag LIKE '%which%'").fetchall()
```

Does anyone know an easy to way to solve this?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Note that you are _selecting_, not _inserting_.

Comment: The format for Python's f-strings is `f"This is an f-string {var_name} and {var_name}."`. 
 You should also be **very wary** of f-strings going directly into SQL queries, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63946987/15291770) points out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have quotes around `:text`:

```py
rows = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM vragen WHERE vraag LIKE :text",
                      {"text": '%' + query + '%'}).fetchall()
```